# Bash-Like syntax parsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I would like to parse the following text using *Pyparsing*:

```
# It is a comment

# It is a comment
# It is a comment
It is not a comment



# It is a comment
It is not a comment
It is not a comment
  It is not a comment


It is not a comment
```

Each block, consisting of optional descriptions and optional content and optional empty lines, is separated by a single newline character. So it doesn't have a known format.

The result that I would like to achieve is the following. Please, note the preservation of the new-lines characters when there are multiple consequential empty lines, very important to compose the original text from the parsed text:

```
[
  {"description": "# It is a comment"},
  {"description": "# It is a comment\n# It is a comment", "content": "It is not a comment\n\n"},
  {"description": "# It is a comment", "content": "It is not a comment\nIt is not a comment\n  It is not a comment\n"},
  {"content": "It is not a comment"}
]
```

I have tried different solutions. The purely regex one works very well, but I would like to take better advantage of the *Pyparsing* tool which seems very interesting to me.

Here is the code implemented which has the problem of continuing in an infinite loop.

```
from pyparsing import Group, Literal, ZeroOrMore, restOfLine

data = '''
# It is a comment

# It is a comment
# It is a comment
It is not a comment



# It is a comment
It is not a comment
It is not a comment
  It is not a comment


It is not a comment
'''


def bnf():
    strip = lambda e: e[0].strip()
    join = lambda e: '\n'.join(e[0])

    number_sign = Literal('#').suppress()

    description = number_sign + restOfLine
    description = description.setParseAction(strip)
    description = ZeroOrMore(description)
    description = Group(description).setParseAction(join)('description')

    content = ~number_sign + restOfLine
    content = ZeroOrMore(content)
    content = Group(content).setParseAction(join, strip)('content')

    elements = Group(description + content)
    elements = ZeroOrMore(elements)

    return elements


tokens = bnf().parseString(data)
print(tokens.dump())
```

I would like, besides solving the problem, to understand why the program hangs in an infinite loop.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: What do you mean by "dotfile" in this case? Is this a specific file format? I've never seen it.

Comment: I did a lot of tests using ZeroOrMore(Literal('#') + restOfLine) to parse the comments and ZeroOrMore(NotAny('#') + restOfLine) to parse the others lines. But without any success.

Comment: @BnG Please post your best attempt. SO is not a code-writing service, but we can help you debug your code. See [ask] for more pointers, as well as [mre].

Comment: Certainly as soon as I have the opportunity to turn on my PC.

Comment: @Iguananaut [Dotfiles](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dotfiles) don't have a specific format, they're just any config file that starts with a dot, like .bashrc, .inputrc, or .ipython. So I'm not sure what OP means. Their example looks a bit like YAML.

Comment: Thanks. I corrected the title.

Comment: `text` is not defined. You meant `data`, right?

Comment: Yes data. I corrected it.

Comment: @wjandrea yeah that's what I normally think of as a dotfile. That's why I thought it was strange to refer to some very specific format as a "dotfile"

Comment: Since your grammar has so many `ZeroOrMore` expressions, I think you may be getting to the end of the input, but then just matching forever on... nothing!  Try changing `elements` to `elements = ZeroOrMore(~StringEnd() + element)`.

Comment: @PaulMcG using the code `elements = ZeroOrMore(~StringEnd() + elements)` nothing changes. I also used a parameter that you implemented, i.e. _stopOn_  `elements = ZeroOrMore(elements, StringEnd())` and nothing changes either. The use of the stop condition _StringEnd_ initially seemed so strange to specify, because I would expect that the parsing of the text ends automatically when the StringEnd is reached. I don't understand the logic of this stop even more of the infinite loop. This means that adding additional `ZeroOrMore` or `OneOrMore` could seriously complicate the debugging of the code.

Comment: However using the _stop condition_ something changes if you use `Word(printables + ' \t')` instead of `restOfLine`.